# How to disable verification of Authenticode signature for a .NET 1.1 assembly?

Tags: digital-signature, .net-1.1

My question is this: How can I stop my .NET 1.1 application from trying to verify the digital signature in an environment where there is no access to the Internet?

Background to my question:
I have a product installed at a customer which is based on  .NET 1.1 SP1. The customer site has no access to the Internet. This causes a delay in application startup which in some cases causes my Windows services to fail to start because they time out.

The delay when starting appears to be caused by the app attempting to verify the digital signature. This is well documented in other posts and the normal answer is to include generatePublisherEvidence=false in the app.config file, as documented here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/936707

It seems that using generatePublisherEvidence=false doesn't make any difference to .NET 1.1 apps, which seems to agree with MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0kk0kk35(VS.71).aspx does not mention the element) and with the hotfix I mentioned above, which was released for .NET 2.0 apps.

My next release to the customer will be built on .NET 3.5 SP1 and I have no problems with using generatePublisherEvidence on that version of the .NET framework, but I currently cannot simply change the customer to that release - I am stuck with .NET 1.1 SP1 - so I'm looking for an answer other than to simply use a later version of the .NET framework.

Comment: Unfortunately we couldn't find a solution for our products and ended up removing an authenticode signature from .NET assemblies altogether. We only use strongnaming. This is simpler for us, because we develop component libraries, not the end-user application.

Comment: I just found this to disable CRL checking by changing a setting in Internet Explorer. I'm going to try this next - will get back with the result:
1. Open Internet Explorer
2. Go to Tools —> Internet Options…
3. Go to the Advanced tab
4. Locate the Security section and uncheck the Check for publisher’s certificate revocation option.

Comment: Hmm. Shame on me. I did not 'get back with the result' as I promised in my previous comment. And now it's so long ago... I'm pretty sure that this solution did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this for a vendor-supplied application today. I assume that their application was written in .net, but I did not confirm. Since the subnet did not have internet access, I removed the DNS server entry from the TCP/IP settings on the local computers that have static addresses. For addresses supplied by DHCP, I removed the DNS server option (006) from the DHCP scope.

Comment: Ah, this is interesting, since we have (still) been observing this problem at the customer site, but only on some machines and not on others. It might be that the difference between the machines that work and those that don't is whether they have static or dynamic addresses... Thanks for the info.

Comment: but this solution may create other problems with applications that need to resolve names...